# How to Tesseract multiple .tif files?

Tags: pdf, ocr, tesseract

a total self-taught noob here. I'm using Windows Command Promt to run Tesseract-ocr.

I managed to find the right command to get as output a two-layers pdf file with the original scanned page BUT ALSO a searchable text.

```
tesseract filename.tif output -l ita pdf
```

Quite simple for me too.
But how do I repeat this operation for all the 200+ .tif files in the folder without doing it manually? It makes no difference to me to get as many output pdfs or to get a single output pdf.

Thanks to everyone who will help me.

Comment: what is desired output? 200+ individual files or 1 file?

Answer (score 1):

I found a way in the meanwhile: create a txt file containing the list of all the paths to each .tif file (with the command `dir/s/b *.tif > listname.txt`) and then use it as input for Tesseract.

Maybe there's a faster way, but this works.